# Calculating best case run time complexity of recursive algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, time-complexity

In class i have started learning how to calculate the run time complexity functions of various algorithms and am finding it difficult. I am trying to calculate the best case rune time complexity of my recursive algorithm below.

At the moment i am choosing my fundamental operation to be a comparison between the index of two chars, and assuming i am trying to find the path where my algorithm outputs a result as soon as possible, i am thinking this first comparison being false would lead my algorithm to do this if i am correct.

Would i be correct in thinking the best case run time complexity function for this algorithm would be t(n) = 1 and in taking the comparison of indexes as a fundamental operation?

```
public class StringShuffleTest {

    public static boolean isOrderedShuffle(String a, String b, String c){

        //variables for the size of Strings a, b and c.
        int n = a.length();
        int m = b.length();
        int len = c.length();     

        //if the length of c is not the length of a + b, return false.
        if (len != (n + m)){
            return false;
        }

        //if String c contains String b as a substring, then remove String b from c and make m = 0.
        //This statement avoids errors when dealing with Strings with very similar characters.
        if (c.contains(b)){
            c = c.replace(b, "");
            m = 0;
        }

        //if the length of a or b is 0, and c equals a or b, return true, otherwise,
        //return false.
        if (n == 0 || m == 0){
            if (c.equals(a) || c.equals(b)){
                return true;
            }
            else
                return false;
        }

        //if String a has length 1, remove a from String c and make String a empty.
        if (n == 1){
                c = c.substring(0, c.indexOf(a.charAt(0))) + c.substring(c.indexOf(a.charAt(0)) +1);
                a = "";
                return isOrderedShuffle(a, b, c);

            }

        //An ordered shuffle of two given strings, a and b, is a string that can be formed by interspersing
        //the characters of a and b in a way that maintains the left-to-right order of the characters from each
        //string.

        //Recursive algorithm to determine if String c is an ordered shuffle of a and b.
        else
        if (c.indexOf(a.charAt(0)) >= 0){

            int indexOfFirsta = c.indexOf(a.charAt(0));
            int indexOfSeconda = c.indexOf(a.charAt(1));

            if (indexOfFirsta <= indexOfSeconda){//Taking as fund operation.
            c = c.substring(0, indexOfFirsta) + c.substring(indexOfFirsta +1);
            a = a.substring(1, n);
                System.out.println(a);
                System.out.println(c);                   
            return isOrderedShuffle(a, b, c);
            }

        else
            if (c.indexOf(b.charAt(0)) >= 0){
                    int indexOfFirstb = c.indexOf(b.charAt(0));
                    int indexOfSecondb = c.indexOf(b.charAt(1));

                    if (indexOfFirstb <= indexOfSecondb){
                        c = c.substring(0, indexOfFirstb) + c.substring(indexOfFirstb +1);
                        b = b.substring(1, m);
                        System.out.println(b);
                        System.out.println(c);

                    return isOrderedShuffle(a, b, c);

                }
        }

        }
    return false;         
    }       

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(StringShuffleTest.isOrderedShuffle("abc", "def", "abedcf")); 

}

}
```

Comment: Yes, the *best*-case time of this algorithm is O(1), because it could be called with two strings of bounded length (e.g. a string of length 0 and a string of length 1) and the first test could fail.  (Whether it's still best-case O(1) on strings of arbitrary length depends on how strings are implemented in Java -- if `length()` has to iterate through all characters to "measure" the length then its best-case complexity can't be better than O(n).)  Usually the worst-case time is more interesting/important, though!

Comment: @j_random_hacker Thank you very much for the comment it was very helpful! Would i then be correct in thinking that the worst case run time complexity for this algorithm would be t(n) = 2N? As i am taking each if statement to be of constant time, and to iterate through every character of length N, two if statements must be performed each time.

Comment: I'm confused.  A statement like `if (c.contains(b))` must take *at least* O(n) time even if an optimally fast string comparison algorithm (like Knuth-Morris-Pratt) is used, and could be as bad as O(n^2) if the naive comparison is used (many programming language standard libraries still implement `contains()` this way).  So it doesn't make sense to me to "take each if statement to be constant time".